# Custom Field view in inline admin form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am using inline model admin and many to many relation. I have two model classes User and Videodata and i linked them with many to many relation. Below is my models

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    user_email = models.EmailField()
    user_city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    videos_watched = models.ManyToManyField('VideoData', through='WatchedVideo')
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user_id']
        verbose_name = 'User MetaData'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users MetaData'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_id

class VideoData(models.Model):
    video_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    video_name = models.CharField(max_length=40) 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User_Video MetaData'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users_Video MetaData'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.video_id

class WatchedVideo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field = 'user_id')
    videoData = models.ForeignKey(VideoData, to_field = 'video_id')
    time  = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True)
```

In User table i see video data but with video_id but i want video_name to be displayed there. I am attaching a link of current output.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0JOKpp3abpzOFN3LVg0WEs3a0k

You can see in above pic video id is there but i want video name. How can i do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the name changing the method `__unicode__` of VideoData to:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.video_name
```

**EDIT**: 
 Add method `__str__` to `VideoData`:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.video_id

def __str__(self):
    return self.video_name
```

Comment: i cannot return video_name because i am using video_id in foreign key link....i tried with that but i got error:"no reference video_id" while uploading fixture data through manage.py command.

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Comment: i am using django 1.8

Comment: okay. Just add the `__str__` method in `VideoData` (I've edited answer)

Comment: one question, why do you type manually the id and don't use the default of django to do the relations?

Comment: because i am loading data from JSON file. In JSON i dont know primary keys of User and Videodata, to resolve this i used user_id and video_id.

Answer (score 0):

I displayed names with following change:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.video_name

def __str__(self):
    return self.video_id
```